# Installation trouble while trying to boot from DVD

Tags: boot, system-installation, dvd

I'm trying to replace Windows Vista on a Toshiba laptop (32-bit), with Ubuntu,
I have done this multiple times with other machines, but this one is not responding to the DVD I created (changed the BIOS settings to boot from disc) I created two discs, one from LTS14 and one with LTS16, tried both. when restarting it just goes right back to the desktop, despite the change in boot menu order

I have tried several times in the past to create USBs and they never, ever, work.

Any other ideas for troubleshooting?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the toshiba laptop does not use (u)efi mode - but I guess the (vista) piece is rather old but you may search your bios settings.
Might as well be some flaw in your aging laptop cd/dvd drive.

Another alternative would be to dd (from the live cd, on another pc) the ISO to a usb stick of proper size (beware, everything on it will be overwritten) and try to set up "boot from usb".

Answer (score 0):

One way to find out whether your BIOS recognises your DVD as it should is to insert the DVD and THEN enter your BIOS -> Boot Order of Devices. Both the entry for the HDD with Vista on it, as well as the entry for your DVD drive should have the name of their respective operating system next to it.
If Vista is recognised, but Ubuntu is not, you should try a different program to crate the DVD (my favourite is UUI for Windows: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/).
If Ubuntu on the DVD is recognised, it is a bit tricky to find the exact problem. Are you absolutely positive that no text appears saying "Press any key to boot from DVD" when booting?